# Body background overlaping Div Image Background

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page that has a background with 2 images, one on the left, one on the right.
Basicly a absolute positioned fixed `DIV` (`#Background`), containing 2 floating DIVs.

On top of these **DIVs** I have multiple **DIVs** all nested in a `container` (`#mainDIV`).

What is strange is wen I scroll down, the body background overlaps the `#Background` DIV.

Any advise?

## CSS

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    
html,
body{
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-10;
}

#Background{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

#Background_Left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/background_left.jpg) fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    background-size:contain;
}

#Background_Right{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/background_right.jpg) fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    background-size:contain;
}

#mainDIV{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

#BotoesContainer{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    background:url(images/banner.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#ConteudoContainer{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:70px;
}
```

## HMTL

```
<body>
<div id="Background">
    <div id="Background_Left"></div>
    <div id="Background_Right"></div>
</div>
<div id="mainDIV">
  <div id="BotoesContainer"></div>
  <div id="ConteudoContainer">Put lots of text here to scroll down</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I removed all the non esencial code, you can see the current page with the `"scroll overlap"` [Demo here](http://www.chazard.eu/teste/cspreguengogrande/pt/home.php)

Comment: The body background is not overlapping the divs, the divs are ending.

Comment: The problems comes from your "height:100%" on the Background div. when you scroll down, the div is not tall enough to fill the rest of the screen so you see some white there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your divs are ending when you scroll down.  You can keep them in place by adding

```
position:fixed;
```

to #Background

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem.So basically is was an illusion, only the background images where fixed, but not the container div... I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your page and inspect the element i have found that you need to add `position:fixed;`  instead of `position:absolute;` in `#Background`

```
#Background{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```